# HTML5 background video not playing on FF, IE11, Chrome for Android and iPhone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio-2013

I can't get my HTML5 background video to play on FF, IE11, Chrome for Android or iOS 8.

I'm using ASP.NET and the BG video will play on Chrome and Opera in Win7, but nowhere else.
After googling around I've managed to set my code up like this:

> web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
</staticContent>
```

> index.html:

```
     <style>
        video#bgvid{
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            position: fixed;

        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body >
    <video id="bgvid" autoplay muted >
        <source src="Video/bg.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="Video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4" />           
        <source src="Video/bg.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
```

> FireFox Error Message:
>
> Media resource MyWebsite/app/Video/bg.mp4 could not be decoded.

Edit:
After moving the .webm file  to the top of the list of scource files, I no longer get that error, but I still get an error which doesn't allow me to play the file:

> SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1

I then switched to the non-minified version and this is the only warning I get:

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.9.1.js:3346

IE11 Returns no errors and I don't know how to debug browsers on Android and iPhone(yet), so I'm not immediately worried about mobile browsers.

I hope that this is enough info. Could you please help?

Comment: how does the HTTP request for you video appear in Chrome Dev Tools? Are you sure it's encoded correctly or have you played it locally?

Comment: Played it both locally and remote. It seems fine in Chrome Dev Tools. I see no errors.

Comment: Your mime type for `.ogv` is wrong in `web.config`, the correct one is what you used in the HTML.

Comment: hmme I've switched it and put .mp4 back on top and now I get the error message:"Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.mp4'" in my web.config file...but I don't have any other entries for this?